# Unlooped Factorials

Tags: code-golf

Write a program to determine if a number is a factorial. You should take the number from standard input.

**Rules:**

- **No using *any* loops** (hint: recursion)
- **Maximum of *one* if statement**
- **No accessing the Internet or external resources**

**Scoring:**

- **+1 per character**
- **-20 for each of the following: (I don't know if any of these are possible)**

  - **Don't use any if statements**
  - **Don't use recursion**

**Lowest score wins**.

**Clarification:**

- **Only if statements in your *source* code count, but any form of if counts.**
- **Any loop constructs in source code count.**
- **You *may* assume int32**

Comment: What will be the maximum input size; can we assume int32 or int64?

Comment: _one_ `if` statement? What about `switch`, the ternary operator and short-circuiting boolean operators?

Comment: What about higher order functions that do recursion internally? Or pattern matching?

Comment: Any solution, if you compile it down to assembly, there will be branching statements. Any kind of actual logic, requires branching.

Comment: Added clarification of rules. Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Does indexing an array of functions count as an `if`?

Comment: I suggest you specify exactly the forms of `if` statements.

Comment: Does `goto` count as a loop?

Comment: @user2509848 No, but you're still bound by one if.

Comment: After your clarification - does indexing an array of functions count as a form of `if`? You need to clarify what constitutes a form of `if`.

Comment: @JanDvorak No. It doesn't count.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>42</s> 41-40 = 1

No recursion or `If` is used (-40)

```
MemberQ[Table[Times@@Range@k,{k,9^4}],#]&
```

**How it works**.

`Times` is `Listable`.  It does not loop when applied to a list. It does the multiplication all at once.

```
Range[6]
```

> {1,2,3,4,5,6}

```
Times@@Range[6]
```

> 720

---

**Testing**

```
MemberQ[Table[Times@@Range@k,{k,9^4}],#]&[720]
MemberQ[Table[Times@@Range@k,{k,9^4}],#]&[721]
MemberQ[Table[Times@@Range@k,{k,9^4}],#]&[10000!]
```

> True
> False
> True

Comment: `NestWhile` uses `If` internally

Comment: @Jan How can you be sure?

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative implementation?

Comment: This will almost certainly be the accepted answer but I'm going to wait a day or so first.

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript: 13, no loops or recursion

```
.,{,(;{*}*}%?
```

Admittedly very inefficient.  Compute every factorial up to `n!` and find `n` in the list.  The top of the stack will be -1 if and only if the input was not a factorial.

Changed to a GolfScript answer I liked better because question was closed.

Comment: I'd say the `foreach` falls into the "loop" category.

Comment: @Howard true.  What about `Select`, though?

Comment: I don't know - ask the questioner (also range, aggregate and contains are actually loops - although they can be implemented without any loop). As it currently stands the task is not defined as clearly that we can tell.

Comment: I don't know C# so I don't know enough to determine what is or is not a loop.

Answer (score 1):

#### GolfScript, 32

Plain approach using recursion (no loops, also no internal loops) and exactly one *if*:

```
~1{1$1$%!@2$/*\)1$2<{;}{f}if}:f~
```

Test the code [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIyNCIKCn4xezEkMSQlIUAyJC8qXCkxJDI8ezt9e2Z9aWZ9OmZ%2B&run=true). It'll print `1` if the input is a factorial number, `0` if not.

We can hide also the *if* using string evaluation:

```
~1{1$1$%!@2$/*\)1$2<'f;'1/=~}:f~
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 characters (26 points?)

```
f=->x,m{x>1 ?f[x/m,m+1]:x==1}
p f[gets.to_r,1]
```

This version is pretty straightworward. It divides by successive integers until the number drops at one or below using bignum rational arithmetic, then returns whether it's exactly one, except it uses tail recursion to do so.

If it's allowed to output the condition inverted, use `x<1` instead of `x==1` for a one-character saving.

The looping version is just 6 characters shorter:

```
x,m=gets.to_r,1
x/=m+=1 while x>1
p x==1
```

Also, can I get a 20-point bonus for using a ternary instead of an `if` statement? If not, can I get it for a pair of short-circuiting boolean operators **(53 characters)**?

```
f=->x,m{p x,m;x>1&&f[x/m,m+1]||x==1}
```

If not, what about an array of functions? This one is too long (even with the bonus) (and unreadable), but it does demonstrate an important point: what does actually count as an `if`?

```
f=->x,m{{true=>f,false=>->_,_{x==1}}[x>1][x/m,m+1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl 53 (93-40)

Only int32?

```
 expr [gets stdin]in{1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880 3628800 39916800 479001600 6227020800}
```

Fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell - 49 (or 29 or 9)

This is one bends unwritten rules: It will not halt for non-factorial inputs.
In practice it does determine if a number is a factorial or not, but then again theoretically you can never know.

```
main=getLine>>=print.(`elem`scanl1(*)[1..]).read
```

Edit: sorry for initially not reading the problem description.

Comment: The task is not about calculating the n-th factorial but to check if n is a factorial.

Comment: Thanks and sorry @Howard. I guess I thought the bolded text included the important parts.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell,  31 = (71C - 20 - 20)

No if statements, no recursion.

```
c n=n`elem`[product[1..n]|n<-[1..n]]
main=do;s<-getLine;print$c$read s
```